# how to create count down timer on button click in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, validation

Hi am trying to do forget password screen in angular

**sinario**

1. user enter's their email id and hit submit button.
2. once the submit button is clicked the button should be disabled and show countdown timer  for 2 minutes I have attached screenshots
3. after 2 minutes back should be back to normal

[before click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZ2Bs.png) and after the click [after click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PEz1.png)

**forgetpassword.component.html**

```
<form class="form-horizontal login100-form m-auto" [formGroup]="loginForm">
          <p class="h4 login-header">Forgot password</p>
          <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
            <mat-form-field [appearance]="'outline'" class="w-100">
              <mat-label>Email-id</mat-label>
              <input matInput formControlName="user_email" #t>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
            <button type="button" class="btn login-button btn-block"
                    (click)="onResetPassword()" [disabled]="f.user_email.errors && f.user_email.errors.required">
              Send password reset
              link
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="contact100-form-checkbox ">
            <div class="d-flex">
              <div class="mr-2">
                <a (click)="forgetpassword = false" class="txt1"
                   style="   font-size: 20px;">Sign-in</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

**forgetpassword.component.ts**

```
onResetPassword() {
const email = this.loginForm.value.user_email;

console.log(this.loginForm.controls.user_email.errors);
this.userService.gerResetPassword(email).subscribe(data => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    console.log(data);
    // this.show = true;
  },
  error => {
    console.log(error);
  }
);
```

}

i found few online source but nothing helped me...

Answer (score 1):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kswlfw

U can use Observable from rxjs library.

Create interval

```
this.timer = interval(1000)
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.ispause)
      );

    this.timerObserver = {

      next: (_: number) => {  
         if(this.time==0){this.ispause.next;}
          this.time -= 1;        
      }
    };
```

and call it in click  function

```
<button (click)="goOn()"> {{secondsToHms(time)}}</button>
goOn() {

    this.timer.subscribe(this.timerObserver);
  }
```

and this function is for format to show timer

```
secondsToHms(d) {
    d = Number(d);
    var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
    var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);

    var mDisplay = m > 0 ? m + (m == 1 ? ": " : " : ") : "00";
    var sDisplay = s > 0 ? s + (s == 1 ? "" : "") : "00";
    return mDisplay + sDisplay; 
}
```

Comment: Hi how to change the button text  based on click or dynamically

Comment: if u connect your variable to interval then when interval goes on your text also will change because u are binding text in html . it always listen time at backend

Comment: am new to angular bro can you explain me with example please...

Comment: Angular is not like javascript. In angular html and typescript works two way. It means if u changed in typescript something then in html it changes automatically. If u change something in html it chages in typescript automatically. And in this example we change time variable every second with timer, and html is changes too automatically when variable change

Comment: Do u understand now ? we are just here changing variable with time interval

Comment: its looks like it can be used only once after if again click that it runs fast